# What metabolically happens when an egg fuses with the nucleus of a somatic cell

Tags: cell-biology, eukaryotic-cells, stem-cells

In stem cell biology, it is recognized that embryonic stem cells are transcriptionally inactive for the first 3 days of development. However, during somatic cell nuclear transfer, the nucleus is likely to include various polymerases and RNA both coding and non-coding. Does this affect the success rates of cloning?

Answer (score 1):

**Somatic cell nuclear transfer** is a method for creating a viable embryo from a somatic cell and egg cell. A *somatic nucleus* is inserted into an *enucleated egg*, where the somatic nucleus is reprogrammed by egg cytoplasmic factors to become a zygote (fertilized egg).

This requires the [use of eggs in metaphase II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatic_cell_nuclear_transfer) of the cell cycle. Somatic cell nuclei must be in interphase (G0/G1). Interphase is the portion of the cell cycle that is not accompanied by observable changes under the microscope.

**What determines the success rates of cloning**

*Oct-4* and other yamanaka factor expression is essential for somatic cell nuclear transfer [**success**](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17562675/) (Pay-wall).

Outlined [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3539358/):

> "...we now think that the oocyte cytoplasm might reprogramme the somatic cell nucleus too strongly, or that the somatic cell nucleus is more sensitive to oocyte reprogramming factors than are sperm cell nuclei."

Thus, Reprogramming and cloning success is unlikely to be influenced by *somatic nucleus polymerases and RNA*.